# Can't get post ID and category using wp_insert_post_data

Tags: wordpress, function

I would like to create post titles automatically. The post title is made from the category and category ID before the post is created in the database but does not get the category and ID.

Any help will be much appreciated, Thank You.

```
function my_post_titles($data, $postarr){

        $postid = $postarr['ID'];
        $postcategory = $postarr['post_category'];

        $data['post_title'] = $postcategory."-".$postid; 

return $data;

}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'my_post_titles', '99', 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to be aware of here: `wp_insert_post_data` is the filter used by `wp_insert_post` to allow changes to its first parameter, so to understand your problem, you should check how `wp_insert_post` works.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Essentially, if the post you are creating a new post, then it should not have any ID (as it's not even created and saved to the database yet). To have access to the post `ID`, I suggest you use `save_post` hook rather than `wp_insert_post`. `save_post` is the action triggered after the post is created or updated. For example:

```
add_action('save_post', function($post_id) {
   $title = get_the_title($post_id);

   if ($title) {
     return; // if the post has already has a title, then do nothing
   }
   // Otherwise, update the post title here
});
```

Also, `$postarr['post_category']` is an array, not a string, so to get the correct information, you must convert it to string before concat it with the post_id.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you help me a little more? Pre-determining a value for each post title. This value will be "xyz". But this code gives the category's name value the name of the first category. How can I add the name of the current category? ` 
add_action('save_post', function($post_id, $post) {
   $title = get_the_title($post_id);
   $postcategory = get_the_category($post_id);
   $category_name = $postcategory[0]->name;  
   if ($title == 'xyz') { wp_update_post( [ "ID" => $post_id, "post_title" => $category_name." - ".$post_id,] ) ;   }
return;
});`

Comment: Basically, for a post object, there is no term called `current category`, if you add multiple categories to your post, it's up to you to decide which category will be selected for your title.